# Ads not visible in whole day, only night for certain time why?

Tags: adsense, admob

I am using Admob account in my app, its work perfectly.
I am getting 30K pageviews but impressions are limited like 2k to 4k .
ads are visible only night and invisible for all day,please help why its happening and what should I Do?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you done any advance setting in the admob? Like CPM rate while creating the ads or you are only showing the ads of the specific categories other all will be blocked by you?

Comment: No any advance setting I have done, by default which setting is comes I am using that.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem and i searched on google for solution.I find that it will automatically fix by google so don't worry wait for 1-2 days it will automatically removed.